# three20 actively developed

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

Is three20 still actively being developed? From the three20.info site, I see no new features/UI elements since earlier this year when I looked into it.

Besides three20, is there another good framework out there?

Comment: From their site: Version 1.0.6.2 July 17, 2011

Comment: But I see no new features/UI elements added, neither updated documentation on the new releases. What's exactly there in the July 17 release and what's planned for the future?

Comment: there are release notes available and there's a community on the site. Did you try to check there?

Comment: I did check three20.info and forum.three20.info, not too much of new stuff on there. The community seems shrinking as well, with just few questions and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, Three20 is only maintained by community (bug fixes). Jeff left the project and decided to clean up that mess & provide solid documentation.

He recently started a new project [on github called Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus), his plan is to port all features of Three20 to Nimbus without the problems we face today with Three20.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't given up on three20 yet. It's a good framework and it saves me hours of work. I'm submitting bug fixes and small improvements to the framework from time to time and I see some activity in github. (not as much as it used to be)

I tried using nimbus, and I was really impressed with the documentation and existing classes. However, note that the developer went to work in CA and said he'll contribute less to his new framework.

The three20.info site is not maintained, but you can download the latest version from [github.com/facebook/three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20).